# Java script is not working inside the weform page of asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio, validation

I'm new to asp .net and I'm trying some of basic validations and I'm struck with this one.
I have added a js script in my web form and also default required field validator which is also not showing any errors

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"     runat="server">
        `<script type="text/javascript">
    function fun() {
        if (Page_ClteientValidate("test")) {
            var x = document.getElementById(("<%= TextBox1.ClientID%>")).Value
            if (x <= 18 && x > 60) {
               Response.alert("Thank You");
                return true;

            }`  
            else {
                Response.alert("Please Enter again")
                document.getElementById("TextBox1").focus();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }</script>
<p>
    entering the following user details: Flight user has to enter the type of travel he has to select either one way or round trip. After that following controls should be displayed to the user User name, From Location, Destination Location, Departure Date, Return Date(only of type of travel is round trip), Preferred Airline (Indigo,Jet Airways, Air India,), Mobile number, Date of Booking
</p>
<p>
    age:<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="test"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="error">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</p>
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" />
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit"   OnClientClick="return fun()"  ValidationGroup="test"/>

</p>
```

Help me to find what's wrong with this code/approch

Comment: Describe your problem in a little more detail. Are you seeing any errors? Is the fun() function getting called?

Comment: No,its not even getting called. When I hit submit it simply post back the page.

Comment: You can set the ValidationGroup of the ValidationSummary, remove the OnClientClick and let the button try to do its postback normally, to see if the error message appears when the TextBox is empty.

Comment: if i remove `onclientclick` how will it validate the js script

Comment: What's this `Page_ClteientValidate` ???

Comment: @vikram - You can try it to see if the RequiredFieldValidator works. If you need more validation, you could use an additional CustomValidator (or do everything in that custom validation) and show all your messages in the ValidationSummary.

Comment: It helps to find which function comes under the group validator of `test`@JCM

Comment: I know about the custom validator but I need to know why this js is not working ?? ConnorsFan